# Collect all items containing a word to a Multimap

Tags: java, stream, guava

I have a simple class like

```
class Item {
    Set<String> wordSet() {...}
}
```

So each `item` has a set of words and I need the inverse relation, i.e., for each word find all `item`s containing it. This gets used a lot, so I want an `ImmutableSetMultimap` allowing me to retrieve it quickly.

I'm using

```
ImmutableSetMultimap<String, Item> wordToItemsMultimap(Collection<Item> items) {
    Multimap<Item, String> itemToWords = items
        .stream()
        .collect(Multimaps.flatteningToMultimap(
             i -> i,
             i -> i.wordSet().stream(),
             HashMultimap::create));
    Multimap<String, Item> wordToItems =
             Multimaps.invertFrom(itemToWords, HashMultimap.create());
    return ImmutableSetMultimap.copyOf(wordToItems);
}
```

for creating the map and it works, but I find it too complicated. I'm looking for a simpler solution.

I don't care much about efficiency of the above snippet (as it gets called just once), but optimization hints are welcome as I'm doing a lot of similar things where speed matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your `items` has no null elements, you can use [`ImmutableSetMultimap#flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html#flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector and it's own [`inverse`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html#inverse--) method instead of calling utility methods.

```
return items.stream()
        .collect(flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap(
                i -> i,
                i -> i.wordSet().stream()
        ))
        .inverse();
```

It's a bit more terse (note the static import, which in my team we agreed is acceptable, although we normally don't use static imports) as it repeats looong class name in method name) and gives you immutable multimap right away.

If some "flattening" version of [`Multimaps#index`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-) existed, you could have also used it, but there's no such method right now unfortunately.